# Silex/Symfony creating traits

Tags: symfony, traits, silex

I created a trait and tried to use it but I face the error that the application object doesn't have the method.

`Call to undefined method Silex\Application::phrase()`

Trying to use

```
use \Language\LanguageTrait
$app->phrase()
```

And this is the language trait.

```
namespace Language;

use Silex\Application;

trait LanguageTrait
    {
        public function phrase ($phrase, $replacements = array())
        {
            $language = $this['language'];

            return $language->phrase($phrase, $replacements);
        }
    }
```

I have tried with other built in traits like the URLServiceProvider trait but I get the same error so I assume I am using it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the default Silex\Application class. The documentation isn't clear that you have to actually create a custom application that extends the default then initialize that. For example:

```
class CustomApplication extends Silex\Application {
    use YourTrait;
}
$app = new CustomApplication();
```

Hope this helps. You can find more information on traits over at http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#traits